# Rewrite CSS and Javascript files in Folder to Gzip Version

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I use the code below in htacess to redirect css and javascript files to the gzip version.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.jgz -f
RewriteRule (.*)\.css$ $1\.css.jgz [L]
RewriteRule (.*)\.js$ $1\.js.jgz [L]
AddType "text/stylesheet" .css.jgz
AddType "text/javascript" .js.jgz
AddEncoding gzip .jgz
```

But i notice that in Wordpress Admin a lot of javascript files are blocked because they didn't exists as gzip version.

So i would like to redirect only javascript and css files from these folders

- domain.de/styles/
- domain.de/scripts/

I want to change this two lines,

- RewriteRule (.*).css$ $1.css.jgz [L]
- RewriteRule (.*).js$ $1.js.jgz [L]

and put the folder /styles/ and /scripts/ into it.

How do I have to adjust the code above? I can not get it though. The styles are no longer displayed.

Comment: Are you offering them for download? Or are you trying to enable Gzip compression in Apache so your files get smaller?

Comment: I'm trying to enable Gzip compression in Apache so the files get smaller

Comment: Well that's not how you do it, you `rewrite` your assets, that's why they are no longer displayed. You need `mod_deflate` active in Apache and something like `AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css application/javascript`  in your `.htaccess`, better search on Stackoverflow

Comment: I want to change this two lines, RewriteRule (.*)\.css$ $1\.css.jgz [L]
RewriteRule (.*)\.js$ $1\.js.jgz [L] and put the folder /styles/ and /scripts/ into it. Mode_deflate is also active but only for images.

Comment: I thought that it is better or more performant to put the GZIP version of the CSS and JS files directly on the server (as physical existing files), so the server do not have to create it on-the-fly. Don't know if i'm right here or if it makes no diffrent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the folders in the regex.

```
RewriteRule ^((styles|scripts)/.*)\.css$ $1\.css.jgz [L]
RewriteRule ^((styles|scripts)/.*)\.js$ $1\.js.jgz [L]
```